# adding LSTM layer but getting required positional argument: 'units' error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to run my first machine learning model. However I am getting the error below.

> return_sequences=True))
>   TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'units'

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Dropout

model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(input_dim=1,
           output_dim=50,
           return_sequences=True))

model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(output_dim=1))
model.add(Activation('linear'))

start = time.time()

model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="rmsprop")
```

Since it said the parameter units was missing I have also tried the below line,

```
model.add(LSTM(100,
           input_dim=1,
           output_dim=50,
           return_sequences=True))
```

Then get this error message but I don't understand why that doesn't come in my first attempt. What am I missing?

> TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'input_dim')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`units` is the first parameter of `LSTM`, which represents the last dimension of the output data at this layer. It shows the first error because your code doesn't have `units` in your first attempt. `units` satisfies the condition so that it shows the second error in the second attempt.

You should use the `input_shape` parameter to specify the shape of the first layer input in this case. Your first `LSTM` layer `input_shape` should have two data (`timestep` and `feature`,`batch_size` doesn't need to be filled in by default) since LSTM requires three dimensional input. Assuming your timestep is 10, your code should be changed to the following.

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Dropout,Activation

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=100,input_shape=(10,1),return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(units=1))
model.add(Activation('linear'))
model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="rmsprop")
print(model.summary())

_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm (LSTM)                  (None, 10, 100)           40800     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 10, 100)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 100)               80400     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 100)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 1)                 101       
_________________________________________________________________
activation (Activation)      (None, 1)                 0         
=================================================================
Total params: 121,301
Trainable params: 121,301
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: thanks for the clear answer, much appreciated. The Activation('linear'), which library is Activation from as my code doesn't recognise it?

Comment: @mHelpMe `Activation` is a keras layer. I added it to the answer.